# AngularJS what's the role of ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

In the following code, when I remove ng-model, there is nothing in the dropdown, however, when I added ng-model it works, i can see the content in the dropdown list. That confused me a lot about the role of the ng-model, in this case, I suppose only adding ng-options, it will work but actually not.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body {
        font: 16px/1.5 sans-serif;
        color: #222;
        margin: 5em;
      }

      select {
        width: 40%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div ng-controller="Option">
      <select 
              ng-model= "aa"
              ng-options="person.name for person in people">
        <option value="">Choose a person</option>
      </select>

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      var Option = function ($scope) {
        $scope.people = [
          {name: "Tom", number: "0199"},
          {name: "Justin", number: "0199"},
          {name: "Jelly", number: "0199"},
        ];
      };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The behavior is strange. You can use `ng-repeat` with `<option>` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

It is the glue between your model and the display control. But aslo does some other stuff:

**ngModel is responsible for:**

- Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as
  input, textarea or select require.
- Providing validation behavior (i.e. required, number, email, url).
- Keeping the state of the control (valid/invalid, dirty/pristine,
  validation errors).
- Setting related css classes on the element (ng-valid, ng-invalid,
  ng-dirty, ng-pristine).
- Registering the control with its parent form.

As mentioned in the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

Answer (score 0):

> ng-model  is like a **name** or **id**  or **property(selected)** for the control
>
> ng-options is like a **option** tag for **select** tag
>
> and `ng-model` helps to shown selected or default option value

Your code should be look like this below way

html

```
<select ng-model= "aa" ng-options="person.name for person in people"></select>
```

Js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var Option = function ($scope) {
        $scope.people = [
          {name: "Choose a person", number: ""},
          {name: "Tom", number: "0199"},
          {name: "Justin", number: "0199"},
          {name: "Jelly", number: "0199"},
        ];
       $scope.aa= $scope.people[0];
      };

    </script>
```